# Datagrid add row add a empty row by default

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The function `InsertProductItem` will add arow into the datgrid. The code work, but it will add a empty row by default. How can I remove it?

Xaml:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgProductList" 
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductList}">
```

Code:

```
public ObservableCollection<SalesItem> _ProductList = new ObservableCollection<SalesItem>();
        public ObservableCollection<SalesItem> ProductList { get { return _ProductList; } set { _ProductList = value; } }

        public SalesWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

public void InsertProductItem(Product product)
        {
            SalesItem item = new SalesItem { ProductName = product.Name, Quantity = 1, TotalPrice = product.Price };
            ProductList.Add(item);
        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set [CanUserAddRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows.aspx) to False on your DataGrid if you don't want to use the DataGrid's default way of adding rows

```
<DataGrid Name="dgProductList" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductList}"
          CanUserAddRows="False">
```

Comment: @FlorianGl I'm sure Kev will, but I posted this a minute or two after the question posted and there's a timer that prevents accepting an answer until after X minutes have passed :)

Comment: Yeah I forgot about this timer, sorry Kevin.^^ I just hate it, when somebody tries hard in solving a problem for the person who is asking and this person is too lazy to mark it as answer.